# Do google pixel laptops (2016) run Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, unity, ubuntu-mate, google

I noticed an [advert](https://web.archive.org/web/20170330031008/http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-Google-Chromebook-Pixel-12-9-TouchScreen-i5-1-8GHz-i5-4GB-32GB-CB001-/302153832443) for a google pixel laptop, and noticed that the service is [still on-going](https://arstechnica.co.uk/gadgets/2017/03/google-says-pixel-laptops-arent-dead-it-just-isnt-announcing-or-selling-any/).

All this time of trying to find a laptop & if it could run Trusty, or Xenial 16.04 on the Pixel laptop - and IDK if it has a proper "Goobuntu" release or not, -or has that bitten the dust too?

Any Alphabet users, if you are using this - please let me know if Unity or Mate works well on the 2016 models.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with a Pixel laptop, but I imagine the hardware isn't that different from the old Chromebooks, in which case it is extremely difficult to boot anything other than Chromium on them. They use flash ROM for their system drive, which is why most of them only have about 64GB of storage. It wasn't designed to be overwritten, just like any ROM device.